# Prices and contracts query

Tags: performance, sql, join

The query below is quite slow (taking about half a second). Any obvious things I could improve?

The `PRICES` table has about 21 million rows and 30 columns while `CONTRACTS` has 130 k rows and 10 columns.

```
SELECT
 CONTRACTS.EXT_ID,
 PRICES.REFERENCE_DATE,
 PRICES.PRICE_DATE,
 CONTRACTS.PERIOD,
 PRICES.TIME_TO_MATURITY,
 PRICES.CLOSE_PRICE,
 PRICES.ORIGINAL_PRICE_ID 
FROM
 PRICES INNER JOIN CONTRACTS ON PRICES.CONTRACT_ID = CONTRACTS.ID 
WHERE
 (((CONTRACTS.EXT_ID)=@CONTRACTID)
 AND ((PRICES.REFERENCE_DATE)=@REFDATE)
 AND ((PRICES.STATUS_TYPE) LIKE 'CAL%'));
```

Comment: What database — is it Microsoft [tag:sql-server]? What indexes exist on your tables?

Comment: @200_success. Tricky bit. It's not my db and I don't have documentation.  That's why I'm looking for 'obvious' things. `PRICES.REFERENCE_DATE` and `CONTRACTS.EXT_ID` would be natural indexes.

Comment: I know it's an oracle db. (jdbc:oracle:thin:)

Comment: @BuckTurgidson just a guess but maybe the condition `(PRICES.STATUS_TYPE) LIKE 'CAL%'` can be sped up by replacing the `LIKE` with a string function call this way `left(PRICES.STATUS_TYPE, 3) = 'CAL'`

Comment: @BuckTurgidson also why not keep a copy of these tables in a database that you do control?  Refresh your database copy whenever you deem appropriate.  This way you can put in indexes anyway you want.  You can also add columns.  For instance, I'd recommend adding a bit column called `IsCal` to your copy that is 1 if `STATUS_TYPE` starts with "CAL" and 0 otherwise.  That way your query won't have any string operations in it.

Comment: @user2023861. Should't it be the opposite? `(PRICES.STATUS_TYPE) LIKE 'CAL%' ` faster then  `left(PRICES.STATUS_TYPE, 3) = 'CAL'` ? any references on this?

Comment: @BuckTurgidson what happened when you ran it?

Comment: Half a second to join 21 million records, seek specific rows, and return? What makes you think that is slow?

Answer (score 1):

if you less care about the "Dirty read" then you can use the "(nolock)" after the table name. 
And you already have the indexing.